# How to remove numbers from string which starts and ends with numbers?

Tags: java, regex

I have two strings

```
 1. J2EE
 2. java1.6
```

I want to remove numbers from only the start and ends; not from between.

Can anyone provide a regular expression for this, or any other solution?

Comment: How results should look like? For instance should `"2. java1.6"` be `" . java1."` or maybe `"java"`?

Comment: only java not . java1.

Comment: Your question says something different. Consider [edit]ing it to add results you want to get and define what you mean by numbers. Maybe mark characters you want to remove.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simple using `replaceAll()` using `^\\d+|\\d+$` regex that looks for digits in the beginning and ending of the line.

```
System.out.println("1adfds23dfdsf121".replaceAll("^\\d+|\\d+$", ""));
```

output:

```
adfds23dfdsf
```

---

*EDIT*

Regex explanation:

```
^     Start of line
 \d+   Any digit (one or more times)
|     OR
 \d+   Any digit (one or more times)
$     End of line
```

[image]

Comment: Explanation would be also nice (mainly what `^` and `$` represents). Also it may be needed to use `MULTILINE` flag.

Comment: What if i want remove only starting numeric ?

Comment: @NarendraSorathiya Use `^` to match starting of the text. Try `^\\d+` to replace starting numeric only.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
String replaced = yourString.replaceAll("^\\d+\\. |(?:\\d+\\.)?\\d+$", "");
```

**Output:**

```
J2EE
java
```

**Explanation**

- `^\d+\.` matches the leading digits, period and space
- '|' OR
- `(?:\d+\.)?\d+$` matches optional digits-and-dot, digits, and end of string
- Replace with the empty string

Comment: +1 for answering something that OP didn't even ask clearly in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
string.replaceAll("^(?:\\d|\\d\\.\\d)*|(?:\\d|\\d\\.\\d)*$", "");
```

This looks for digits at the end and/or start of the string, and replaces them with nothing. It will also remove decimal dots (`.`)

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\\d|\\d+\\.\\d+)*` a digit or a number with a decimal (`1234.4321`)
- `*` zero or more times
- `|` or
- `$` end of the string